# Firefly artful dodger starting drive core

Tags: firefly

In firefly, the bonus ship (the artful dodger) available in more recent printings of the game has several differences, including a different drive core.

During set-up, the players are supposed to take a drive core from the set of starting drive cores, however there is no such card for the artful dodger. The same drive core is however available for purchase within the game.

Should the pilot of the artful dodger play without any card for their starting drive core, and take the effects as written? or should they claim the corresponding core from the purchase decks, removing it from the pool for other players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter.

> To use the Artful Dodger, during set-up pull a "Modified Radion Accelerator Mark II" drive core from the Osiris Supply Deck to serve as the Artful Dodger's starting drive core. With its faster core and higher crew capacity, captaining the Dodger means working fewer delivery jobs and focusing on riskier, more profitable crime jobs.

That's from the [product's BGG page](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/145481/firefly-the-game-artful-dodger). It looks like a quote from an official source.

Answer (score 1):

While this is the official answer for the base game, the boxed Artful Dodger add-on came with its own drive core card. So (assuming you don't have this add-on) it would also be reasonable to make your own starting drive core, and leave the Osiris deck alone.